# Finding number of occurrences of items in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two supplied bits of information: A dictionary of transactions and a list of the unique items in the transactions.

```
transactions = {
   "T1": ["A", "B", "C", "E"],
    "T2": ["A", "D", "E"],
    "T3": ["B", "C", "E"],
    "T4": ["B", "C", "D", "E"],
    "T5": ["B", "D", "E"]
}
items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

What I need to do is find the number of occurrences of these items in the transactions. I created a dictionary that has keys representing the unique items and the value for each key initialized to 0, but I am unsure of how to update these values to represent the number of occurrences in the transactions.

```
occurr = dict()
for x in items:
    occurr[x] = 0
```

This is my occurrences dictionary which yields the output:

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0}
```

The final dictionary should look like:

```
{'A': 2, 'B':4, 'C': 3, 'D': 3, 'E': 5}
```

as 'A' occurs 2 times in the transactions, 'B' occurs 4 times, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are in the right direction. You need to iterate over the values of dictionary.

```
occurr = dict()
for x in items:
    occurr[x] = 0

for transaction in transactions.values():
    for item in transaction:
        occurr[item] += 1
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate all lists to single list and call `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
items = [item for transaction in transactions.values() for item in transaction]
print(collections.Counter(items))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

transactions = {
    "T1": ["A", "B", "C", "E"],
    "T2": ["A", "D", "E"],
    "T3": ["B", "C", "E"],
    "T4": ["B", "C", "D", "E"],
    "T5": ["B", "D", "E"]
}

c = Counter()

for dd in transactions.values():
    c.update(dd)

print(c) # or c.items(), c.keys() or c.values()

# Result: Counter({'E': 5, 'B': 4, 'C': 3, 'D': 3, 'A': 2})
# Note that the result is a subclass of dict
```

This will count the frequency of all values in `transactions`. If you need to restrict to those keys present in `items` then filter for that.

Alternatively, [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) the transaction list values into a single list, and count that in one call. For example:

```
flatlist = [item for sublist in transactions.values() for item in sublist]
print(Counter(flatlist))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
transactions = {
    "T1": ["A", "B", "C", "E"],
    "T2": ["A", "D", "E"],
    "T3": ["B", "C", "E"],
    "T4": ["B", "C", "D", "E"],
    "T5": ["B", "D", "E"],
}
items = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

out = {}
for l in transactions.values():
    for v in l:
        out[v] = out.get(v, 0) + 1

out= {k: out.get(k) for k in items}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 3, 'D': 3, 'E': 5}
```